# Script to check for file system usage and clear space

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I am pretty new to shell scripts I have few unix systems of different distro's (RHEL, CENTOS, FEDORA, UBUNTU) Is there any way to have a script to check for the filesystem disk space usage example below

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  6.7G  2.3G  4.4G  34% /
devtmpfs                 361M     0  361M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    371M     0  371M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    371M  5.1M  366M   2% /run
tmpfs                    371M     0  371M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M  124M  374M  25% /boot
tmpfs                     75M     0   75M   0% /run/user/0
```

and to check if any of the disk has diskspace more than 90% and it clears the space.

Comment: How would a script know which files to (safely) delete? If root fills up, should it delete kernel? What if you're keeping them for some reason? Kernel source-- ditto? Core dumps -- ditto!

Answer (score 1):

You posted `df -h` output, which is human readable, but not good for scripts.

You probably want to pay closer attention to column 4 (avail) than to the percentage in column 5.

It sounds like your script knows about ancient log files that are "safe" to prune. For a given pruning operation, that set of files will be on exactly one filesystem. It makes no sense to parse systemwide `df` output when you really care about this:

```
cd /var/log
df -k . | awk '{print $4}'
```

That gives a numeric report in KBytes (rather than with human readable text suffixes) on exactly the quantity you care about, free space for current directory's filesystem. You can write a while loop around that, perhaps pruning a single file, the oldest file, each time through the loop. Include a sanity check before beginning the loop: ensure that `du -k` says that you could free "enough" space if needed. It's no fun to delete `dir1/*` only to find that `dir2/giant_file` was the one you should have been focusing on.